# Merge tags [idempotent] [idempotence] and [idempotency]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Currently, we have the following three tags on Stack Overflow that all refer to the same concept:

- [idempotent](/questions/tagged/idempotent) (with 20 questions)
- [idempotence](/questions/tagged/idempotence) (with 5 questions)
- [idempotency](/questions/tagged/idempotency) (with 3 questions)

Two of them should be made synonyms. I don't know which tag would be best as the master tag, probably [idempotence](/questions/tagged/idempotence), as that is the name of the concept.

Only the [idempotent](/questions/tagged/idempotent) tag has a tag wiki, so that needs to be copied into the new master tag.

EDIT: The above was not my suggestion. The powers-that-be have put things into my mouth here. I agree with the suggestion to retag the 8 other questions to [idempotent].

Comment: someone already made the tags synonym, when I wrote my answer they were still all there :)

Comment: You needed *some* words there...

Comment: @TheEstablishment Perhaps, but I didn't need my suggestion to 'merge' turned into your suggestion for synonyms that I didn't make.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Retagging  [idempotence](/questions/tagged/idempotence) questions and [idempotency](/questions/tagged/idempotency) questions to [idempotent](/questions/tagged/idempotent) might be the easiest way. It is quickly done.

The unused tags will disappear if no one uses them after 24h.

Answer (score 1):

Idempotent is both the most popular, and the one that is used the most in everyday conversation, [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends/?q=idempotent,%20idempotence,%20idempotency) also suggests this is the most searched for version.

I personally would definitely choose idempotent as the canonical tag

Comment: All of that may be true, but the tag synonym system makes it all irrelevant. Even if someone were to enter or search for "idempotent", they would automatically get whichever tag we choose.